# Ruby in JS in HAML: what's the syntax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got this JS at the end of my HAML view:

```
:javascript
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('leadsMap')),
      markers = [],
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    - @leads.each do |lead|
      - next unless lead.latitude && lead.longitude
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: #{lead.latitude}, lng: #{lead.longitude}},
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
```

How can I parse the `@leads` so that the loop works correctly? As it stands I get a `undefined local variable or method 'lead'` error.

Comment: Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to (a) move the JavaScript to a separate file and (b) serialize `@leads` to JSON (possibly filtering out entries with missing coordinates first) and handing that JavaScript data to your JavaScript function? Trying to mix languages like you are almost always leads to tears and frustration and it tends to be a big ugly mess even when you can make it work.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd make it into a partial for the time being. Probably smarter design.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...
%script
  - @leads.each do |lead|
    - next unless lead.latitude && lead.longitude
    var lead_latitude = "#{lead.latitude}";
    var lead_longitude = "#{lead.longitude}";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: lead_latitude, lng: lead_longitude},
      map: map
    });
...
```

I forget if google maps api allows lat and lng in string, but you can convert `lead_latitude` and `lead_longitude` to their need (`parseInt`, `parseDouble`, etc).

if you still insist putting ruby variable inside js in haml

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) 59 accomplish this if you really want to have your Ruby variables in JS.

That said, I'd strongly recommend against using script tags since ideally for security reasons you would want to block all script tags, thus preventing most forms of XSS.